# jquery slider pics loading error

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, slider

i recently purchased a slider and implemented it on my php photo album, the problem is when i click on the pic to open the slider as a lightbox it only shows one pic on which i click . and the next and previous slide option gets wasted .

i used mysql query

```
   $s=mysql_query("select * from gallery where albumId='$vp' and userId='$id'");
```

this grabs all the pics in the slider and the slider next and previous pic function works good. but now when i click on any of the photo from my album the default photo [the very fist one in order] gets displayed instead of the one i click and the rest also for previewing next and previous pictures. this hapnd because of select * but how to load all the pictures in the slider and at the same time that picture  open in the slider on which i click allowing the rest of the pictures to be viewed also ?? any idea , m stuck bad , looks my money got wasted .

**update**

first i click on my album then it opens a gallery with more then 20 pics . 
then i click on any of them and the slider opens .

if i use `$s=mysql_query("select $picid from gallery where albumId='$vp' and userId='$id'");`

in this specifying the pic id in the slider itself the pic on which i click opens . but the
next and previous button doesnt works are only one pic gets in slider

if i use `$s=mysql_query("select * from gallery where albumId='$vp' and userId='$id'");`

all the pics open up in side the slider but not the one which i click at the fst place
for eg . there are 20 pics . i clicked on pic number five . then the slider opens with 
pic number one . i want that it opens with the pic i clicked plus next and previous pics could be viewed too.

Comment: how many records does your query fetch from database, did you check you have more than one image for a particular user in its album... may that is the error, or u can just let us know what error do you get..

Comment: if you have purchased it then its better to ask the vendor about the problem... anyway can you post some relevant javascript code thats responsible for firing up the slider

Comment: yes ill post some javascript code , as the vendor is not responding from 2 days and m really stuck bad at this

Comment: @ murtaza and @3nignma thanks for respoding . i cleared it out more what is happening. please see if could help me out . thank you

Answer (score 0):

ur query seems to be ok.. 
I think u need to have a look at ur javascript code
Something like this..

```
// here the code knws user album id and pic id which u have clicked.. & u can make a check here ... some condition like clickid == picid..

this.click = this.addControl('clickid'); //declaration 4 click event for the pic u wanna display..
if( !this.options.Slide ){
     $(this.options.thumbsContainer).addEvent('clickid', function(ev){
       new Event(ev).stop();
       this.click.fireEvent('clickid');         
      }.bind(this));
}
else{
      //---- the code for the normal operation (like in ur case it starts with first pic).
}
```

Hope it wrks.. :)